# Запись даных в БД, используя fictures

Tags: python, django

При попытке записать данные в БД через

```
python manage.py loaddata region
```

из файла region.json выдает ошибку

> django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError:
> Problem installing fixture
> '/home/.../fictures/region.json': need
> more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: Откуда вы взяли файл `region.json`?

Comment: Из папки fictures. А в settings.py прописал к ней путь: 

FIXTURE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'fictures/'),
).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django использует название папки  не fictures, а **fixtures**, которая в свою очередь должна лежать в директории апликейшена, и вы, как я вижу, собственноручно прописали DIRS, но если удалить FIXTURE_DIRS и переименовать папку в fixtures, то Джанга сама найдет.